# F# CSV Parsing to C# App

Tags: c#, csv, f#

I have a C# console application that calls a F# library that does some CSV parsing by using the CSVTypeProvider. (http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/reference/fsharp-data-csvprovider.html)

Unfortunately i'm somewhat new to F# and so i haven't found a way to efficiently hand the parsed data from F# to C# in form of a List of C# objects.

Suppose i have an C# Data Model:

```
public class Customer{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then i want to transform the data from the csv type provider to a list of that model:

```
Extractor extractor = new Extractor();
List<Customer> customers = extractor.Data;
```

With the Extractor being defined as:

```ml
module internal FileLoader =
    type = Customers = CsvProvider<"C:\somefilePath", HasHeaders = true>

    let customers = Customers.Load<"C:\someFilePath">

type Extractor() =
    member this.Data = FileLoader.customers.Rows |> Seq.map(fun row -> new Customer(row.ID, row.Name))
```

From there i thought i could simply import the Datamodel into the f# library and use the map function to map the row values to the c# object but that doesn't quite seem to work.

Edit:

I found a solution, but i'm still open to a more elegant one.

I simply have to create the class that i want in C# (Customer) in the F# Library.

```ml
type Customer(ID : int, Name : string) =
    member this.ID = ID
    member this.Name = Name
```

Then i can use the mapping function to convert the rows to the customer objects and import the customer type to c#.

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  What happens instead of the expected outcome?

Comment: When i access the data property of the extractor i get the complete rows instead of a list of objects. What i need is the conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define my model class in the F# project like so

```ml
type Customer = {id:int;name:string}
```

then in your map you can

```ml
Seq.map(fun row -> {id=row.id;name=row.name})
```

and return as an IEnumerable to your C# code.

Comment: I had the same i idea just moments ago.